# preg_match_all id of url with words

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I want to get the news id from  URL with php preg_match_all;

```
     $pattern = '%^(http://xxxxx/t)([0-9].?)+^(-)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i';

         $m = preg_match_all($pattern,$uu,$matches);    
print_r ($matches);
```

Example URL formats:

```
http://www.xxxx.com/t1134133-0
http://www.xxxx.com/t1134133-news-news-worlds
http://www.xxxx.com/t1134133-mi%20&ffjfj
```

i need to get 1134133 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way would be get the last part first and then do regex to get numeric part.

Something like:

```
//get the last part
$arrayUrl=explode("/",$url);
$finalPath=$arrayUrl[count($arrayUrl)-1];

preg_match("/\d+/",$finalPath,$matches);
```

or If you're pretty sure that the url patterns are absolutely similar to example in OP you can even simply do like

```
preg_match("/\d+/",$url,$matches); // where url is `http://www.xxxx.com/t1134133-mi%20&ffjfj`
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => -0 [1] => 0 )

Comment: how to do same with my sql select ?

Comment: you will be using `where news_ID like '%whatever%'`